# Why Dir.glob in Ruby doesn't see files in folders named with square brackets?

Tags: ruby, linux

I have this tree :

```
.
├── folders
│   ├── foo
│   │   └── fuu.flac
│   ├── foo [bar]
│   │   └── fuu.flac
│   └── foo[bar]
│       └── fuu.flac
└── test.rb
```

and this code :

```
#!/bin/env ruby
## encoding: utf-8

Dir.glob('./folders/*').each do |path|
  puts "Contents of #{path} :"
  Dir.glob(File.join(path, '*')).each do |file_path|
    puts "\t #{file_path}"
  end
end
```

I expect to see my three fuu.flac files. However the script doesn't show the files in the folders with square brackets in the name.

Here is the output :

```
Contents of ./folders/foo [bar] :
Contents of ./folders/foo[bar] :
Contents of ./folders/foo :
     ./folders/foo/fuu.flac
```

Is this a normal beahvior of Ruby, or did I miss something ?

(I am using Ruby 1.9.3 under Ubuntu 12.10)

Comment: UGH. Don't use `[` and `]` or other special characters in file and directory names. That way is full of dragons and terrible beasts you don't want to encounter, at all sorts of levels, such as annoyed sysadmins and other users who can't manipulate the names or search because some other app doesn't like it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The square brackets have a [special meaning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29#Syntax) in the context of shell globbing. `foo[bar]` matches `foob`, `fooa` or `foor`, but obviously not `foo[bar]`. If you really want to dynamically generate such a pattern, you will need to at least escape the characters `\?{}[].` using a backslash:

```
def escape_glob(s)
  s.gsub(/[\\\{\}\[\]\*\?]/) { |x| "\\"+x }
end

# ...
Dir.glob("#{escape_glob(path)}/*").each do |file_path|
  # ...
end
```