# List all paths recursively when name of top directory may contain glob characters

Tags: ruby, glob

In Ruby, we can recursively list all the contents of a directory like so:

```
dir = '/tmp'
Dir.glob("#{dir}/**/*") # Works
```

However, this fails if the directory has glob characters in its name

```
dir = '/tmp/test[folder]ing'
Dir.glob("#{dir}/**/*") # Does not work
```

One solution when we don’t know the name of the directory that will be passed to our script (e.g. when it’s given as an argument), is to preemptively escape problematic characters from its name

```
dir = '/tmp/test[folder]ing'
escaped_dir = dir.gsub(/([\*\?\[\]{}\\])/, '\\\\\1')
Dir.glob("#{escaped_dir}/**/*") # Works
```

This works but it’s a bit ugly, feels hacky, and requires keeping track of two variables for slightly different things (the unescaped name is useful for other operations).

Are there other solutions to this same problem (that ideally wouldn’t be too slow to run in comparison)?

Comment: Guess still missing this function in ruby: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8258 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14127343/why-dir-glob-in-ruby-doesnt-see-files-in-folders-named-with-square-brackets

Comment: If you don't mind using Unix `find` tool ... `%x{find "#{dir}"}.split("\n")` ... you can add `-type f` after the `#{dir}` to return only files

Answer (score 0):

[`Pathname`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html) can do it:

```
require 'pathname'

dir = '/tmp/test[folder]ing'
Pathname(dir).glob('**/*')
```